# Service isn't running Task.run

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I have written a windows service.
Below are the global variables defined inside class:

```
private static TimeSpan pollingInterval;
private static Thread regenerationThread;
private static ManualResetEvent quitThreadEvent;
private static ConcurrentQueue<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

Here is the start method for service:

```
internal static void Start()
{
    pollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
    quitThreadEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    regenerationThread = new Thread(doStart);
    regenerationThread.Start();
}
```

Here is the doStart method mentioned above:

```
internal static void doStart()
{   
    queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user1", "password1"));
    queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user2", "password2"));
    queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user3", "password3"));
    while (!quitThreadEvent.WaitOne(pollingInterval))
    {
        // tempList isn't empty, I checked it putting logs here.
        if (tempList.Length != 0)
        {
            var temp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>();
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out temp))
            {
                string username = temp.Key;
                string password = temp.Value;
                // Method comes till here but doesn't execute the statement below and directly reach to end WriteToFile method.
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await tempFunc(username, password);
                    queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(username, password));
                });
            }
        }
        WriteToFile("End of Method");
    }
}
```

I am not sure why `Task.Run` isn't working. I have put logs but it doesn't show any errors. I have tried putting logs inside the `Task.run` but it doesn't show those logs.  Is the reason that I am starting a thread and then calling `Task.run` inside it?

Comment: why don't you use `Task.Run()` instead of threads ?

Comment: There is no need for Task.Run at all in this context

Comment: I didn't get you. Are you suggesting instead of `regenerationThread = new Thread(doStart);` and `regenerationThread.Start();` statement. Initiate method `doStart` using `Task.Run()` ? @Clint

Comment: your `DoStart()` can be a `async Task DoTask()`

Comment: @SirRufo, Actually I want `tempFunc` method to be called multiple times asynchronously, So I think `Task.Run` is the way to do that right? Or I am missing something here?

Comment: Yes, you do ... just wait to get my first coffee of the day and I will post you how

Comment: Can you show the `tempFunc` method? Also please fix the syntax error in the line `WriteToFile("End of Method);`

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten your code to only use async/await pattern.

```
private static TimeSpan pollingInterval;
private static Task regenerationTask;
private static CancellationTokenSource quitThreadEvent;
private static ConcurrentQueue<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

internal static void Start()
{
    pollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
    quitThreadEvent = new CancellationTokenSource();
    regenerationTask = ExecuteAsync( quitThreadEvent.Token );
}
```

```
internal static async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{   
    queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user1", "password1"));
    queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user2", "password2"));
    queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user3", "password3"));
    while ( true )
    {
        await Task.Delay( pollingInterval, cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait( false );
        // tempList isn't empty, I checked it putting logs here.
        if (tempList.Length != 0)
        {
            var temp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>();
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out temp))
            {
                string username = temp.Key;
                string password = temp.Value;

                // fire and forget task - we do not want to await
                // so we do not need to store the task instance
                _ = WorkWithAsync(username, password);
            }
        }
        WriteToFile("End of Method");
    }
}

private static async Task WorkWithAsync( string username, string password )
{
    await tempfunc( username, password ).ConfigureAwait( false );
    queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(username, password));
}
```

If you miss the `Stop` method

```
internal static void Stop()
{
    quitThreadEvent.Cancel();
    regenerationTask.Wait();
}

internal static async Task StopAsync()
{
    quitThreadEvent.Cancel();
    await regenerationTask;
}
```

Comment: `await Task.Delay( pollingInterval, cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait( false );` what exactly does this do? Let's say I have a `async` method and as I have to put `await` in that but I don't want to wait for anything else. So if I put `pollingInterval` as 0, in the statement above, will that do that job? Trying to understand the statement I mentioned.

Comment: Actually talking about `tempFunc`, if I have a bunch of statements in `tempFunc` and I just don't want to wait anywhere and go through the method asynchronously, making `await Task.Dealy(0)` will do that for me?

Comment: @sporty_1993 `Task.Delay( ... )` will wait for the given delay, but throws an exception when the cacellationToken is on cancel state. That is somehow like your ManualRestEvent. `ConfigureAwait( false )` will cause the task to **not** capture the current SynchronizationContext and will continue on a worker thread.

Comment: `Task.Delay( 0 ).ConfigureAwait( false )` is the same as if you write nothing. If you want to continue an a worker thread you have to `await Task.Delay( 1 ).ConfigureAwait( false );`

Comment: In the code you mentioned, so the code execution will stop for `pollingInterval` at `await Task.Deay()` and then will proceed further, right? but here `await tempFunc(username, password).ConfigureAwait( false );` it will just continue after this in the main thread and simultaneously run `tempFunc`

Comment: @sporty_1993 why in the **main** thread? After the first `await Task.Delay( ... ).ConfigureAwait( false );` we are on a worker thread

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the execution will not wait at `await tempFunc(username, password).ConfigureAwait( false );` i.e. will not wait for tempFunc to return.

Comment: I wanted to ask  that `await tempFunc(username, password).ConfigureAwait( false );` will this wait here for tempFunc to be finished? or it will again go ahead in the while loop running tempFunc at a worker thread and again come at `if (tempList.Length != 0)` even if previous `tempFunc` is still running.

Comment: Yes it will wait - I did this because of your comment *Method comes till here but doesn't execute the statement below and directly reach to end WriteToFile method* - if you do not want to wait for it, then you should not be surprised that End of Method will be written to the file before tempfunc finshes or even get started yet. I can update my answer with a no waiting

Comment: Actually `tempList` is getting filled by a service. So I wanted that I execute `tempFunc` (which kind of deletes the element in tempList) and `tempFunc` can keep on running on a different thread, and even if tempFunc is still running, execution reached at the start of while to check if `tempList` is filled againa and execute `tempFunc` on a different thread again. The updated answer of yours does that I think? It will not stop at `_ = WorkWithAsync(username, password);` now will move to the start of while right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207490/discussion-between-sporty-1993-and-sir-rufo).

Answer (score 0):

Though your code is not a good implementation way as people say, your code should also work unless there is something wrong with your code else where. I tried locally and it works. But 'while (!quitThreadEvent.WaitOne(pollingInterval))' blocks the code inside from executing for 'pollingInterval'(100 seconds) unless you set the quitThreadEvent somewhere else. Make sure your program doesn't end before 100 seconds. If it ends early, you may not see the execution results.
And this is one working version code:

```
    internal static void Start()
    {
        pollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        quitThreadEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        regenerationThread = new Thread(doStart);
        regenerationThread.Start();
    }

    internal static void doStart()
    {
        queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user1", "password1"));
        queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user2", "password2"));
        queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user3", "password3"));
        while (!quitThreadEvent.WaitOne(pollingInterval))
        {
            // tempList isn't empty, I checked it putting logs here.
            if (true)
            {
                var temp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>();
                if (queue.TryDequeue(out temp))
                {
                    string username = temp.Key;
                    string password = temp.Value;
                    // Method comes till here but doesn't execute the statement below and directly reach to end WriteToFile method.
                    Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        await tempFunc(username, password);
                        queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(username, password));
                    });
                }
                Console.WriteLine("End of the method.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    internal static async Task tempFunc(string userName, string pwd)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"UserName = {userName}, Pwd = {pwd}");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

`

Comment: I am setting quitThreadEvent only when I stop the service. But still the method was not being called, I am not sure why.